# Kivy: returning animated gif and then calling another def

Tags: python, kivy, animated-gif

After a button is clicked, the app is supposed to display a very heavy table so I would like to first display an animated `gif` and then display the table.

When the button is clicked, a first def is called with this:

```
wait_image= Loading()
self.add_widget(wait_image)
Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: self.DisplayTable(self), 0)
```

But this only load the first frame of the animated `gif`. If I replace the `Clock.schedule` by `return self`, then the animated gif works but the `DisplayTable` def isn't called:

```
wait_image= Loading()
self.add_widget(wait_image)
return self
```

I tried to call another def that will return self, and then proceed with th `DisplayTable` but this also doesn't work (the .gif isn't animated but the table is displayed):

```
Loading_image(self)
Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: self.DisplayTable(self), 0)
```

with :

```
def Loading_image(self):
    wait_image= Loading()
    self.add_widget(wait_image)
    return self
```

So how can I, with a simple click, called and display an animated gif and then proceed to call the DisplayTable def?

---

Here is the `Builder` and the `Loading` class:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<Loading>
    source : 'loading.zip'
    anim_delay : 0.02
    allow_stretch : True
    keep_ratio : True
    keep_data : True
''')
class Loading(AsyncImage):
    pass
```

The code is [here](https://github.com/EnoraNedelec/FoldersManager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the event loop time to update your gif...  Using **kivyoav** makes it simple:

```
from kivyoav.delayed import delayable

@delayable
def DisplayTable(self):
    for i in ROWS:
        yield 0.01 # after each row the gif will have time to update ... 
        for j in COLS:
            pass # build your table cols ...
```

Another choice is to do the heavy lifting in a different thread and only update the UI later using **Clock.schedule_once**

```
def build_table():
   ...
   #stuff that take time
   stuff = ...
   ...
   Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: build_ui_table(stuff)) #since you can use the UI only from the main thread
threading.Thread(target=build_table).start()
```

Comment: Thanks Yoav. I was able with your plugging to get the animated gif, but it isn't running smoothly. The table takes about 15 seconds to be created : the gif is animated for about 2 sec then it get stuck for about 8 sec and then it's moving slowly for the 2 sec and then it get stuck another time for the last 3 sec. During the 15 second, my code is building a BoxLayout with many rows each containing several scrollable Label. The whole BoxLayout is itself scrollable. After that, I add the BoxLayout at once to the app, so I don't understand why the .gif get stuck most of the time.

Comment: I will be hard to help without in code, did you try to put the **yield** in more places? (maybe for each cell that your building?)

Comment: Yes, this is better, but now the .gif is sometimes going back and also the many yield are really slowing down the programs (more than 3 min compare to 15 sec before). I put the code at https://github.com/EnoraNedelec/FoldersManager. The relevant part are `##3`    `##5`   and  `#anim_gif`  in the FoldersManager.py

Comment: Are you yielding 0.1 or 0.0? this can make huge speed difference

Comment: With both yield 0.0  and yield 0.1, the table takes 3 min to be displayed (without the yield, it takes 15 sec). Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: How many "yields" are there? each yield will let the screen update, In you example, the update is heavy since you putting a lot of widgets...